# Sorting elements in a list into 3 individual lists python

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop

Let me start off with the code and explain the goal and what i'm getting.

```
temp1 = ['3.8', 'Weiss, Earl', '139 RATINGS', '2.3', 'Jeppson, Catherine', '114 RATINGS', '3.3', 'Kiani-Aslani, Rajabali', '88 RATINGS', '2.6', 'Lundblad, Heidemarie', '82 RATINGS', '2.4', 'Stone, Ronald', '75 RATINGS', '3.7', 'Vedd, Rishma', '66 RATINGS', '3.3', 'Foster, Robert', '60 RATINGS', '4.9', 'Basmadzhyan, Babken', '59 RATINGS', '4.3', 'Grodsky, Marilyn', '57 RATINGS', '2.4', 'Dorsey, Norris', '53 RATINGS', '2.6', 'Zvinakis, Kristina', '51 RATINGS', '3.2', 'MacKlin, James', '50 RATINGS', '2.8', 'Liu, David', '48 RATINGS', '3.2', 'Doron, Michael', '48 RATINGS', '2.1', 'Rogoff, Donald', '45 RATINGS', '3.1', 'Sangeladji, Mohammad', '43 RATINGS', '4.0', 'Fountaine, Howard', '42 RATINGS', '4.6', 'Stout, Gary', '41 RATINGS', '3.4', 'Gray, Glen', '34 RATINGS', '3.0', 'Wilson, Barbara', '31 RATINGS', '4.0', 'Yoon, Sung-Wook', '31 RATINGS', '4.5', 'Her, Young-Won', '31 RATINGS', '3.0', 'Kiddoo, Robert', '30 RATINGS', '3.0', 'Chiu, J', '27 RATINGS', '3.3', 'Barker, Robert', '25 RATINGS', '3.7', 'Qureshi, Mahmood', '23 RATINGS', '3.7', 'Primes, David', '22 RATINGS', '2.6', 'Chen, Raymond', '20 RATINGS', '3.3', 'Jones, Christopher', '20 RATINGS', '3.2', 'Zhan, Jun', '20 RATINGS', '4.6', 'Bell, Janice', '15 RATINGS', '3.8', 'Alhashim, Dhia D', '12 RATINGS', '2.9', 'Ansari, Shahid', '11 RATINGS', '4.5', 'Rousselet, Robin (rob)', '9 RATINGS', '2.4', 'Lucero, Terrence', '8 RATINGS', '1.0', 'Perez, Marlene', '7 RATINGS', '1.3', 'Crespo, Patricia', '7 RATINGS', '4.8', 'Knight, Ridgeway', '7 RATINGS', '2.5', 'Julius, Ed', '6 RATINGS', '2.9', 'Reinstein, Todd', '6 RATINGS']
```

So my goal is to sort this giant list into 3 different categorical lists,

Professor names, professor ratings, and amount of ratings

I have developed the following for-loop with the following if statements, and as much as a try to play with it atleast one doesn't work out, Let me show you in the following code

```
counter = 1
for index in temp1:
    if counter % 1 == 0:
        pro_rating.append(index)
    if counter % 2 == 0:
        pro_name.append(index)
    if counter % 3 == 0:
        pro_amount_rating.append(index)
        counter = 0
    counter += 1

print("All Professor ratings: ", pro_rating)    
print("All professor names: ", pro_name)
print("Amount of times professor rated: ", pro_amount_rating)
```

Now everything works out pretty well when appending the names (pro_names) and amount of ratings (pro_amount_rating), But pro_rating always writes out the full list.

I completely understand why it's happening, it's because I'm resetting my counter once it hits the 3, and my counter adds 1 at the very end, making the first if statement always true.

I was thinking of placing a flag or a second parameter which would solve this problem but I just can't seem to figure it out, I know I can easily make another forloop to solve this problem but I want to get them all done within this single for loop.

If anyone has any ideas I would appreciate it!

OUTPUT:

```
All Professor ratings:  ['3.8', 'Weiss, Earl', '139 RATINGS', '2.3', 'Jeppson, Catherine', '114 RATINGS', '3.3', 'Kiani-Aslani, Rajabali', '88 RATINGS', '2.6', 'Lundblad, Heidemarie', '82 RATINGS', '2.4', 'Stone, Ronald', '75 RATINGS', '3.7', 'Vedd, Rishma', '66 RATINGS', '3.3', 'Foster, Robert', '60 RATINGS', '4.9', 'Basmadzhyan, Babken', '59 RATINGS', '4.3', 'Grodsky, Marilyn', '57 RATINGS', '2.4', 'Dorsey, Norris', '53 RATINGS', '2.6', 'Zvinakis, Kristina', '51 RATINGS', '3.2', 'MacKlin, James', '50 RATINGS', '2.8', 'Liu, David', '48 RATINGS', '3.2', 'Doron, Michael', '48 RATINGS', '2.1', 'Rogoff, Donald', '45 RATINGS', '3.1', 'Sangeladji, Mohammad', '43 RATINGS', '4.0', 'Fountaine, Howard', '42 RATINGS', '4.6', 'Stout, Gary', '41 RATINGS', '3.4', 'Gray, Glen', '34 RATINGS', '3.0', 'Wilson, Barbara', '31 RATINGS', '4.0', 'Yoon, Sung-Wook', '31 RATINGS', '4.5', 'Her, Young-Won', '31 RATINGS', '3.0', 'Kiddoo, Robert', '30 RATINGS', '3.0', 'Chiu, J', '27 RATINGS', '3.3', 'Barker, Robert', '25 RATINGS', '3.7', 'Qureshi, Mahmood', '23 RATINGS', '3.7', 'Primes, David', '22 RATINGS', '2.6', 'Chen, Raymond', '20 RATINGS', '3.3', 'Jones, Christopher', '20 RATINGS', '3.2', 'Zhan, Jun', '20 RATINGS', '4.6', 'Bell, Janice', '15 RATINGS', '3.8', 'Alhashim, Dhia D', '12 RATINGS', '2.9', 'Ansari, Shahid', '11 RATINGS', '4.5', 'Rousselet, Robin (rob)', '9 RATINGS', '2.4', 'Lucero, Terrence', '8 RATINGS', '1.0', 'Perez, Marlene', '7 RATINGS', '1.3', 'Crespo, Patricia', '7 RATINGS', '4.8', 'Knight, Ridgeway', '7 RATINGS', '2.5', 'Julius, Ed', '6 RATINGS', '2.9', 'Reinstein, Todd', '6 RATINGS']
All professor names:  ['Weiss, Earl', 'Jeppson, Catherine', 'Kiani-Aslani, Rajabali', 'Lundblad, Heidemarie', 'Stone, Ronald', 'Vedd, Rishma', 'Foster, Robert', 'Basmadzhyan, Babken', 'Grodsky, Marilyn', 'Dorsey, Norris', 'Zvinakis, Kristina', 'MacKlin, James', 'Liu, David', 'Doron, Michael', 'Rogoff, Donald', 'Sangeladji, Mohammad', 'Fountaine, Howard', 'Stout, Gary', 'Gray, Glen', 'Wilson, Barbara', 'Yoon, Sung-Wook', 'Her, Young-Won', 'Kiddoo, Robert', 'Chiu, J', 'Barker, Robert', 'Qureshi, Mahmood', 'Primes, David', 'Chen, Raymond', 'Jones, Christopher', 'Zhan, Jun', 'Bell, Janice', 'Alhashim, Dhia D', 'Ansari, Shahid', 'Rousselet, Robin (rob)', 'Lucero, Terrence', 'Perez, Marlene', 'Crespo, Patricia', 'Knight, Ridgeway', 'Julius, Ed', 'Reinstein, Todd']
Amount of times professor rated:  ['139 RATINGS', '114 RATINGS', '88 RATINGS', '82 RATINGS', '75 RATINGS', '66 RATINGS', '60 RATINGS', '59 RATINGS', '57 RATINGS', '53 RATINGS', '51 RATINGS', '50 RATINGS', '48 RATINGS', '48 RATINGS', '45 RATINGS', '43 RATINGS', '42 RATINGS', '41 RATINGS', '34 RATINGS', '31 RATINGS', '31 RATINGS', '31 RATINGS', '30 RATINGS', '27 RATINGS', '25 RATINGS', '23 RATINGS', '22 RATINGS', '20 RATINGS', '20 RATINGS', '20 RATINGS', '15 RATINGS', '12 RATINGS', '11 RATINGS', '9 RATINGS', '8 RATINGS', '7 RATINGS', '7 RATINGS', '7 RATINGS', '6 RATINGS', '6 RATINGS']
```

SOLVED:
Thank you Michael for the solution, I was overthinking clearly, Using a simple 
counter == 1, 2... solved the problem, instead of using a modulo thanks again

Comment: Try simply `if counter == 1:`, `if counter == 2:`, ...

Comment: Well I don't understand why I didn't even think about that LOL, thanks alot bud worked like a charm

Comment: You can just use `enumerate`. Also, if you use `n%i`, you do not need to set counter to 0. for example, `3%3 == 6%3 == 9%3 = 0`, etc ...

Comment: Oh I didn't realize this either, thank you for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use list slicing to achieve what you want with much less code.

```
pro_rating        = temp1[0::3]
pro_name          = temp1[1::3]
pro_amount_rating = temp1[2::3]
```

This would sort the 1st element into rating, the 2nd element into name and the 3rd into amount, repeating for every 3rd element.

Comment: Wow this looks extremely clean, will definitely use this method

Answer (score 1):

It'll be cleaner to change the line `counter % 1 == 0` to `counter % 3 == 0`. Remember that you want every third element so you'll want to modulus with 3 and check that the remainder is 0.

Then you can stop resetting the counter in the third if block and change that to `counter % 3 == 2`. I'll leave it as an exercise to figure out what the middle if block should be.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a nested list storing the rating, the professor's name, and the number of times the latter has been rated:

```
from collections import namedtuple
import re
professor = namedtuple('professor', ['rating', 'name', 'ratings'])
d = ['3.8', 'Weiss, Earl', '139 RATINGS', '2.3', 'Jeppson, Catherine', '114 RATINGS', '3.3', 'Kiani-Aslani, Rajabali', '88 RATINGS', '2.6', 'Lundblad, Heidemarie', '82 RATINGS', '2.4', 'Stone, Ronald', '75 RATINGS', '3.7', 'Vedd, Rishma', '66 RATINGS', '3.3', 'Foster, Robert', '60 RATINGS', '4.9', 'Basmadzhyan, Babken', '59 RATINGS', '4.3', 'Grodsky, Marilyn', '57 RATINGS', '2.4', 'Dorsey, Norris', '53 RATINGS', '2.6', 'Zvinakis, Kristina', '51 RATINGS', '3.2', 'MacKlin, James', '50 RATINGS', '2.8', 'Liu, David', '48 RATINGS', '3.2', 'Doron, Michael', '48 RATINGS', '2.1', 'Rogoff, Donald', '45 RATINGS', '3.1', 'Sangeladji, Mohammad', '43 RATINGS', '4.0', 'Fountaine, Howard', '42 RATINGS', '4.6', 'Stout, Gary', '41 RATINGS', '3.4', 'Gray, Glen', '34 RATINGS', '3.0', 'Wilson, Barbara', '31 RATINGS', '4.0', 'Yoon, Sung-Wook', '31 RATINGS', '4.5', 'Her, Young-Won', '31 RATINGS', '3.0', 'Kiddoo, Robert', '30 RATINGS', '3.0', 'Chiu, J', '27 RATINGS', '3.3', 'Barker, Robert', '25 RATINGS', '3.7', 'Qureshi, Mahmood', '23 RATINGS', '3.7', 'Primes, David', '22 RATINGS', '2.6', 'Chen, Raymond', '20 RATINGS', '3.3', 'Jones, Christopher', '20 RATINGS', '3.2', 'Zhan, Jun', '20 RATINGS', '4.6', 'Bell, Janice', '15 RATINGS', '3.8', 'Alhashim, Dhia D', '12 RATINGS', '2.9', 'Ansari, Shahid', '11 RATINGS', '4.5', 'Rousselet, Robin (rob)', '9 RATINGS', '2.4', 'Lucero, Terrence', '8 RATINGS', '1.0', 'Perez, Marlene', '7 RATINGS', '1.3', 'Crespo, Patricia', '7 RATINGS', '4.8', 'Knight, Ridgeway', '7 RATINGS', '2.5', 'Julius, Ed', '6 RATINGS', '2.9', 'Reinstein, Todd', '6 RATINGS']
grouped_data = [d[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(d), 3)]
results = [professor(float(a), b, int(re.findall('^\d+', c)[0])) for a, b, c in grouped_data]
```

Output:

```
[professor(rating=3.8, name='Weiss, Earl', ratings=139), professor(rating=2.3, name='Jeppson, Catherine', ratings=114), professor(rating=3.3, name='Kiani-Aslani, Rajabali', ratings=88), professor(rating=2.6, name='Lundblad, Heidemarie', ratings=82), professor(rating=2.4, name='Stone, Ronald', ratings=75), professor(rating=3.7, name='Vedd, Rishma', ratings=66), professor(rating=3.3, name='Foster, Robert', ratings=60), professor(rating=4.9, name='Basmadzhyan, Babken', ratings=59), professor(rating=4.3, name='Grodsky, Marilyn', ratings=57), professor(rating=2.4, name='Dorsey, Norris', ratings=53), professor(rating=2.6, name='Zvinakis, Kristina', ratings=51), professor(rating=3.2, name='MacKlin, James', ratings=50), professor(rating=2.8, name='Liu, David', ratings=48), professor(rating=3.2, name='Doron, Michael', ratings=48), professor(rating=2.1, name='Rogoff, Donald', ratings=45), professor(rating=3.1, name='Sangeladji, Mohammad', ratings=43), professor(rating=4.0, name='Fountaine, Howard', ratings=42), professor(rating=4.6, name='Stout, Gary', ratings=41), professor(rating=3.4, name='Gray, Glen', ratings=34), professor(rating=3.0, name='Wilson, Barbara', ratings=31), professor(rating=4.0, name='Yoon, Sung-Wook', ratings=31), professor(rating=4.5, name='Her, Young-Won', ratings=31), professor(rating=3.0, name='Kiddoo, Robert', ratings=30), professor(rating=3.0, name='Chiu, J', ratings=27), professor(rating=3.3, name='Barker, Robert', ratings=25), professor(rating=3.7, name='Qureshi, Mahmood', ratings=23), professor(rating=3.7, name='Primes, David', ratings=22), professor(rating=2.6, name='Chen, Raymond', ratings=20), professor(rating=3.3, name='Jones, Christopher', ratings=20), professor(rating=3.2, name='Zhan, Jun', ratings=20), professor(rating=4.6, name='Bell, Janice', ratings=15), professor(rating=3.8, name='Alhashim, Dhia D', ratings=12), professor(rating=2.9, name='Ansari, Shahid', ratings=11), professor(rating=4.5, name='Rousselet, Robin (rob)', ratings=9), professor(rating=2.4, name='Lucero, Terrence', ratings=8), professor(rating=1.0, name='Perez, Marlene', ratings=7), professor(rating=1.3, name='Crespo, Patricia', ratings=7), professor(rating=4.8, name='Knight, Ridgeway', ratings=7), professor(rating=2.5, name='Julius, Ed', ratings=6), professor(rating=2.9, name='Reinstein, Todd', ratings=6)]
```

Comment: I really like the format that you have, this makes the information looks extremely clean, I'm going to have to take this and analyze it to see exactly what's going on I appreciate the information!

Answer (score 0):

> You can just use enumerate. Also, if you use n%i, you do not need to set counter to 0. for example, 3%3 == 6%3 == 9%3 = 0, etc ...

You've been wrong on  the origin of your problem: 
counter % 1 == 0 actually means is counter a multiple of 1 ?

And every number is a multiple of 1.
You avoid the problem with 2 and 3 by resetting to 0 cause they are prime numbers but keep in mind that 6%3 =6%2 = 6%1